# For $A=\{\sin (2n\pi/7) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\},$ how do I find $\sup(A)$ and $\min(A)$?

Tags: analysis

I'm kinda new at this and I know what $\sup$ and $\min$ mean, but the problem is when calculating them like the example above. Can you enlighten me please?

Comment: Think about it for a while! Start plotting! Or listing elements! What do you know about suprema/infima of finite sets?

Comment: $A$ is finite..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
i) $−1≤\sin(x)≤1$.
ii) Now here the values of the set depends only on $\{\sin (0), \sin (\frac {2\pi}7), \sin (\frac {4\pi}7), \sin (\frac {6\pi}7), \sin (\frac {8\pi}7), \sin (\frac {10\pi}7), \sin (\frac {12\pi}7)\}$. So it is finite. Now just check the minimum & maximum value. because after this the values are repeating.

Comment: you made it so easy thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Call $a_n = \sin(2\pi n/7)$. For every $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$, you have
$$a_{n + 7k} = \sin(2\pi n /7 + 2 k \pi) =  \sin(2\pi n /7) = a_n.$$
Thus, you just need to check the minimum and the maximum among $\{a_0,...,a_6\}$.